# How WSSE UsernameToken Id is generated in WCF

Tags: asp.net, typescript, wcf

I am trying to generate a soap message for a WCF service. The service is using `UserNameOverTransport` with message security version `WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10`.

I got the header sample

```
<o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-7f6455d4-42ab-49fa-8b25-35427c00bb7a-1">
                <o:Username>xxx@xxx.com</o:Username>
                <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">yyyyy</o:Password>
            </o:UsernameToken>
```

The client is not going to be in `.Net`. Can anyone help me in figuring out how the id is generated.

Comment: It seems as an output of an [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) algorithm.

Comment: I want how the hash is generated. Like MD5(Username + created) . or MD5(base64(username+created)) etc.,

Answer (score 0):

If you ask this question because your authentification is not working, you likely don't need the Id label.

As we can see in [this](http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/specs/ws-security/ws-security.htm) specification from xmlsoap.org website,

> **4.1. UsernameToken Element**
>   */UsernameToken/@Id*
>   A string label for this security token.

This element is just a label and its goal is just to provide identification to the UsernameToken element (you can name it with "myToken" or something else).